# Using libraries in android studio

Tags: android

How can I solve this error?

[image]

> Error:(28, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:autofillHints'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autofill framwork works for Android SDK version 26 and above. Make sure you have updated your build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 26
}

compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:autofillHints` is part of version 26 of framework. You seem to be building your app using SDK v25.